# Get information from multidimensional json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get back information from a multidimensional json array but can't seem to get it right.

Below is an example of the output from the url which you can see yourself at `http://109.255.189.130:3000/`

```
{ "vnc_version": "2.1.0.0", "mod_version": "1.0.0.0", "server": { "name": "Pure Blood", "framework": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0" }, "stats": { "uptime": 53462.0, "uptime_peak": 53462.0, "online": 1, "online_max": 1, "online_peak": 2, "unique": 1, "unique_max": 1, "unique_peak": 2, "items": 111752, "items_max": 112259, "items_peak": 112259, "mobiles": 37963, "mobiles_max": 37976, "mobiles_peak": 37978, "guilds": 0, "guilds_max": null, "guilds_peak": 0 }, "players": [ { "info": { "id": 1, "name": "aN.Droid", "title": "", "profile": "", "guild_id": -1, "guild_abbr": "" }, "stats": [ ], "skills": [ ], "equip": [ ] } ], "guilds": [ ] }
```

What I would like to do is echo the name in the players array. There will be more than one player.

Can anyone please help me out here and point me in the correct direction to get this information?

I am very new to json so excuse my ignorance on the subject.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = '{ "vnc_version": "2.1.0.0", "mod_version": "1.0.0.0", "server": { "name": "Pure Blood", "framework": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0" }, "stats": { "uptime": 54383.3, "uptime_peak": 54383.3, "online": 1, "online_max": 1, "online_peak": 2, "unique": 1, "unique_max": 1, "unique_peak": 2, "items": 111672, "items_max": 112259, "items_peak": 112259, "mobiles": 37944, "mobiles_max": 37976, "mobiles_peak": 37978, "guilds": 0, "guilds_max": null, "guilds_peak": 0 }, "players": [ { "info": { "id": 1, "name": "aN.Droid", "title": "", "profile": "", "guild_id": -1, "guild_abbr": "" }, "stats": [ ], "skills": [ ], "equip": [ ] } ], "guilds": [ ] }';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
// you want 'true' as the second parameter so it tunrs this JSON data into a multidimensional array instead of objects.

foreach($array['players'] as $player){
    print_r($player['info']);
    //etc.. do what you want with each player
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works but when I replace the $json variable with $json = file_get_contents('http://109.255.189.130:3000/'); I get garbage back. Do you have any ideas as to why or if I am using file_get_contents incorrectly?

Comment: Fixed it. The output was compressed :) Using curl I got around it. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{ "vnc_version": "2.1.0.0", "mod_version": "1.0.0.0", "server": { "name": "Pure Blood", "framework": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0" }, "stats": { "uptime": 53462.0, "uptime_peak": 53462.0, "online": 1, "online_max": 1, "online_peak": 2, "unique": 1, "unique_max": 1, "unique_peak": 2, "items": 111752, "items_max": 112259, "items_peak": 112259, "mobiles": 37963, "mobiles_max": 37976, "mobiles_peak": 37978, "guilds": 0, "guilds_max": null, "guilds_peak": 0 }, "players": [ { "info": { "id": 1, "name": "aN.Droid", "title": "", "profile": "", "guild_id": -1, "guild_abbr": "" }, "stats": [ ], "skills": [ ], "equip": [ ] } ], "guilds": [ ] }';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr["players"] as $player) print($player["info"]["name"]."<br/>");
```